# Is there a way in typescript to force a type to accept a string directly but not through reference?

Tags: typescript

What I am trying to achieve is a type that allows any string literal to be assigned directly to a variable but disallow references to strings.

```
const A = 'a';
const letter1: MagicType = 'a'; // allowed
const letter2: MagicType = A; // not allowed
const other: string = letter1; // letter1 should end up as type string
```

Is something like this possible with typescript?

Comment: no it does not have that. I wish it did

Comment: I would change your question to talk about string literals, not references

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual difference between the two assignments, by writing `const letter2: MagicType = A;` you are not creating a new reference to the same string, you are actually copying `A` into `letter2` as `string` is a **primitive** type. Then why would you disallow it? Anyway, TypeScript does not make any difference between the two.

You could replace `MagicType` with `string`, it would allow only `string` primitives which can have only one reference. On the other hand, the `String` type would allow any string literal, and also `String` class instances, which can have multiple references.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **branded types**.  They are supported in the [io-ts library](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/index.md#branded-types--refinements) and directly in [the ts-brand library](https://github.com/kourge/ts-brand).

Basically, you can define a subtype of `string` (or `number` or, I suppose, `Date`) that you have to manual accede to.  The classic example is email addresses.  All email addresses are strings, of course, so it is formally a subtype, and there is a function that can decide whether or not a string is a well-formed email address.

Comment: Branded types can still be passed around as variables. In fact, it's mostly the only way to do it - most branding implementations don't treat a raw value as a branded one and require some sort of transformation, e.g., `email: BrandedEmail = brandEmail("abc@def.gh")`. Then you can use this branded variable directly: `email2: BrandedEmail = email` yet OP wants to restrict this.